# Want to style divs inside parent div using grid

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox

I need to design a parent div in a way that divs appear like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

It should appear like this:

```
|1|4|
|2|5|
|3|6|
```

Also the parent div must be divided into column style where 1, 2, 3 should come in order for left-side and 4,5,6 in the right side of wrapper div

Comment: Do you mean you want two columns with 1 2 3 in the first column. Have a go with grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the one you want?

```css
.parent {
  column-count:2;
  color:red;
  column-gap:5px;
  
  }
 
.number {
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid white;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid black;
  }
  
.number:hover {
  background-color:#fff; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="number">1</div>
  <div class="number">2</div>
  <div class="number">3</div>
  <div class="number">4</div>
  <div class="number">5</div>
  <div class="number">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using grid like this:-

```
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 20px);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 20px);
}
```

Comment: You are somewhat right but, all the div are coming in one column here. What I want is in desktop view, it should be 1, 2, 3 in left section and 4,5,6 in right and not 1,2,3,4,5,6 in one column

Answer (score -1):

You mean like this?

```css
.parent {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto auto auto;
  color:red;
  background-color:gray;
  }
 
.number {
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid white;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid black;
  }
  
.number:hover {
  background-color:#fff; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="number">1</div>
  <div class="number">2</div>
  <div class="number">3</div>
  <div class="number">4</div>
  <div class="number">5</div>
  <div class="number">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to transpose this view

Comment: transpose in what way? you mean if you want it in 2 column and 1 column?. If so all you need to change is grid-template-columns:auto auto; (for 2 columns) and grid-template-columns:auto;(for 1 column)

Comment: I have updated my question. please revisit the description

Comment: I got the solution:

<div class="parent">
  <div style=""width:50%; float:left">
     <div>1</div>
     <div>2</div>
     <div>3</div>
  </div>

  <div style=""width:50%; float:right">
     <div>4</div>
     <div>5</div>
     <div>6</div>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: that will work as well. easiest way is column-count:2; that wil position accordingly. I think you saw my other answer.